# ASCII code generation for the combination of keys

Tags: javascript, dom-events, ascii, extended-ascii

I want to know how to get the ASCII code for the combination of keys. Like I want to handle event for some unique key combination [<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>].

Alternatively can you please tell me the ASCII code for [<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>], [<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are flags on the `event` object that tell you if the <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> keys have been entered:

```
if (event.shiftKey) {}
if (event.altKey) {}
if (event.ctrlKey) {}
```

To get the key code (e.g. <kbd>space</kbd>), you need to check the `event.keycode` (13 will get you <kbd>enter</kbd>)

```
if (event.keyCode === 13){}
```

Comment: Space isn't a key, it's a char. But checking `event.keyCode` works for the Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't really standard mappings from keyboard codes to [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).  Maybe this [PC keyboard scan code table](http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm) will help.